# Drag text item in MS Word and create Content Control on mouse up event using Office JavaScript API

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am working on document automation solution through which user can drag item from custom text list (Task Pane) in to the Word document. I want to create add-in using Office.js.

In VSTO we are getting button down event where we have handle DragDrop:

```
if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    strValue = (sender as Button).Text;

    ThisAddIn.objWordApplication.Selection.SetRange(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    (sender as Button).DoDragDrop(" ", DragDropEffects.All);
    oCC1 = ThisAddIn.objWordApplication.ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlText);
    oCC1.Range.Text = strValue;
}
```

Using Office.js, is it possible to achieve same thing from html container (Task pane) to Word document?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot handle button events in Office JS, but that's a good idea. Please suggest that at [Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).